# How to address numerical underflow problem in Naive Bayes classification?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, naivebayes

I have functions to implement Naive Bayes classifier (for my dataset) without using any ML library.
I would like to know how to address numerical underflow problem in this code. I know I need to use log to calculate probabilities in the classifier but I am unable to get it to work. When I print p1 and p0, I am currently getting 0 as output for both. How do I change the function to calculate the probabilities p0 and p1 with log.

```
# build a naive bayes classifier
def classifyNB0(vec2Classify, p0Vec, p1Vec, pAbusive):
    p1 = np.prod(np.power(p1Vec, vec2Classify)) * pAbusive
    print('p1 =',p1)
    # element-wise power computation
    p0 = np.prod(np.power(p0Vec, vec2Classify)) * (1.0 - pAbusive)
    print('p0 =',p0)
    if p1 > p0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Values in p1Vec:

```
p1Vec = [0.05263158 0.15789474 0.05263158 0.         0.         0.05263158
 0.         0.05263158 0.         0.10526316 0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
 0.10526316 0.05263158 0.         0.         0.05263158 0.
 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.        ]
```

Values in vec2Classify:

```
vec2Classify = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: I'd say your best bet is probably to use logarithms for numerical stability. Your exponentiation becomes multiplication and your products become sums, making things much more numerically stable.

Comment: @simon `p1 = sum(np.log(np.prod(p1Vec, vec2Classify))) + math.log(pAbusive)` I tried this but I am getting error `only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. I'm new at python so I probably made a mistake.

Comment: That's probably because of the math.log. Use np.log instead. Also in terms of mathematics your formula is incorrect. It should be np.sum(vec2Classify*np.log(p1Vec)) + np.log(pAbusive)

Comment: Actually... on second thought it shouldn't be the math.log... it's probably the np.prod since you are passing vec2Classify as the axis argument

Comment: @simon This is what I got `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log`. I think np.log is the way to go as p1Vec and vec2Classify are an array. I printed `np.sum(vec2Classify*np.log(p1Vec)` on its own and the result was `nan`

Comment: That's due to zero's in p1Vec. Numerically you can prevent this by clipping the values with np.clip

Comment: Btw with these values for p1Vec and vec2Clasiffy, the original 0 was simply correct.

Comment: You do not really have an underflow problem. I've tried to input your data, and quite frankly, `p1` evaluates correctly to `0.0`. If you take a closer look at `vec2Classify`, you'll see that it only holds `1` at three different indices, and that `p1Vec` is `0` at the exact same indices.

If `p1Vec` is `0` at at least one of the indices where `vec2Classify` is `1`, then the whole `p1 = prod( ... )`  will always be zero.

Maybe your input data (p1Vec, vec2Classify) is incorrectly typed? Please take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose that this is actually a math problem, and that your post might be better suited for [Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

I agree with @simon, this is best solved by some "logarithms", but first I suggest doing some work with pen and paper to simplify the code:

I know nothing about "Naive Bayes Classification", but as far as I can see from your code, you essentially need to evaluate the inequality, `p1 > p0`. Let's do some math..

Obviously, we could equivalently evaluate `log (p_1) > log (p_0)`. So let's try to rewrite the two expressions for `p1` and `p0`.

[image: The Math displayed is by compiled by LaTeX, then screenshotted and pasted here ..]

In code, we would you will need to iterate over your lists/vectors to get the sums..

`log_p1 = log(p1) = V[0]*log(U[0]) + ... + V[n]*log(U[n]) + log(pA)`

Depending on your numerical values, I would hope that these calculations would not be subject of underflow and thus, possible to evaluate: `log_p1 > log_p0`.

In terms of python code the sums would be,

```
import numpy as np

log_p1 = np.log(pAbusive)
log_p0 = np.log(1-pAbusive)
for i in range(len(p1Vec)):
  log_p1 += vec2Classify[i] * np.log(p1Vec[i])
  log_p0 += vec2Classify[i] * np.log(p0Vec[i])
```

And then just evaluate,

```
log_p1 > log_p0
```

**EDIT:**
When I look at your data which you added to the post in a later edit, your math becomes trivial.You don't need `power` nor `log`. You can avoid them all together. Note that,

`power(x,0) = 1`,

`power(x,1) = x`,

`log(1) = 0`,

... **always!**.

You could simply write,

```
p1 = pAbusive
for x,y in zip(p1Vec, vec2Classify):
  if y: # == 1
    p1 *= x
```

Or, as a one-liner list-comprehension

```
p1 = pA * np.prod([x if y else 1 for x,y in zip(p1Vec,vec2Classify)])
```

If you get underflow from this, try again with log,

```
log_p1 = np.log(pA) + sum([np.log(x) if y else 0 for x,y in zip(p1Vec,vec2Classify)])
# ...
# and evaluate,
log_p1 > log_p0
```

**EDIT2:**
You do not really have an underflow problem. I've tried to input your data, and quite frankly, `p1` evaluates correctly to `0.0`. If you take a closer look at `vec2Classify`, you'll see that it only holds `1` at three different indices, and that `p1Vec` is `0` at the exact same indices.

If `p1Vec` is zero at *at least* one of the indices where `vec2Classify` is `1`, then the whole `p1 = prod( ... )`  will **always** be zero, because you'll multiply with `power(0,1) = 0`.

Maybe your input data (`p1Vec, vec2Classify`) is incorrectly typed?

Comment: Thanks, this makes it much more easier to understand.

Comment: @Miztory I'm glad I made the math easier for you. However, when I look at your data which you added to the post in a later edit, your math becomes trivial. Please take a look at my edited answer. Also, since you haven't accepted the answer, maybe you could elaborate on what is still not working as intended?